# SugarCRM, WSDL and RPC

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, sugarcrm

There are many url for SugarCRM CE Web Service API like:

```
http://localhost/soap.php?wsdl
          AND
http://localhost/service/v2/soap.php?wsdl
http://localhost/service/v3/soap.php?wsdl
http://localhost/service/v4/soap.php?wsdl
http://localhost/service/v4_1/soap.php?wsdl
```

They all produce WSDL for **RPC/Encoded**

When I consume the WSDL using **wscompile** Java tool with command line

```
wscompile -gen:client config.xml -keep
```

and config.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-rpc/ri/config">
   <wsdl location="http://localhost/service/v4_1/soap.php?wsdl" packageName="com.crm.imported"/>
</configuration>
```

I could get the generated classes.
But all the URLs have different structure in the generated classes.

Moreover, only the classes generated by **http://localhost/soap.php?wsdl** is working and the rest of them give error:

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: Runtime exception; nested exception is: 
    unexpected element type: expected={http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}QName, actual={http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int
```

***My Questions:***

1. What is the difference in the API versions?
2. What is this XMLSchema QName error? How to solve it.

Comment: I will accept the answer if any one of them is answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answers:

1. All the API version have different implementations.
   For example: Later versions expect password to be MD5 coded.
2. XMLSchema Error is raised by providing wrong information to the parameters.
   java.rmi.RemoteException will simply give the error message irrelevantly.